# Firebase e-mail authentication system logs-in any account:

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application I'm building with **Firebase**. Essentially, I'm trying to build an authentication system that allows users to sign-up using their **e-mail/password** and then use that same **e-mail/password** to log in.

While my ***create users*** authentication system is working just fine, along with my ***reset password*** system that sends password reset links to the designated e-mail address, for some reason or another my **login authentication system** seems to allow anyone of any e-mail address (signed up or not) to sign-in and essentially be authenticated.

***To summarize:*** **Upon entering an e-mail or password in my LoginViewController, it immediately segues into the next ViewController regardless of whether the account has previously been created or not.**

---

**These are the pods I'm using:**

```
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

**Here's my code in my LoginViewController for e-mail/password authentication:**

```
@IBAction func loginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let email = textFieldLoginEmail.text, let password = textFieldLoginPassword.text {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            // There was an error logging in to this account!
           print("Unsuccessful sign-in")
        } else {
            print("Successful login!")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SuccessfulAuthentication", sender: nil)
        }
    })
  }
}
```

**My database rules in my Firebase console:**

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

---

Also, I'm using the exact same code (*with the exception of migrated syntax from **Firebase 2.5.1 to Firebase 3.5.2***) in another application I've built using **Firebase 2.5.1** (Legacy console) and it works exactly as it should and does not log-in any accounts that haven't been created beforehand (sign-up).

---

**UPDATE FIXES:** Firebase version ***3.6.0*** (*release date:* *9/14/16*):

> - Improved the behavior of Firebase Authentication when testing apps using the iOS 10 simulator.
> - Fixed an issue with error reporting when a user provides an invalid email address while signing in with an email address and password.

**[See newest release notes here.](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios)**

Comment: Added update fix + link for release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you create the segue by ctrl dragging from your login UIButton? If yes, then the segue will be performed regardless whether the authentication was a success or not.

You need to make sure when creating the segue in the storyboard that you ctrl+drag the View Controller (I think it's the yellow button at the top of your view controller) not your UIButton

Answer (score 0):

Use `.isValidated` to check whether the logged in user has validated their email address.  As for authorization, remember that is different from authentication.  Authorization is handled by Firebase Realtime Database Rules.